# unable to run powershell command via command prompt

Tags: powershell, cmd

The following command runs fine via powershell.

```
gwmi Win32_Product -filter "name like 'Java%' AND vendor like 'Oracle%' AND not version = '8.0.770.3'" | % { $_.Uninstall() }
```

I'd like to run this without using a script file or opening powershell, but by just calling powershell.exe via command prompt. I get the following error

A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'java%'.

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be a problem with quotes.

When using `powershell.exe` inside batch (to run a PowerShell command), you should especially watch for quoting rules.

Batch uses mainly double quotes, so you can safely do the following:

- Put the whole PowerShell command in a script block, surrounded with double quotes and the `&` operator to make PowerShell invoke the command.
- Replace all double quotes in your command with single quotes.
- Double all single quotes inside the WMI filter.

The end result should look like:

```
powershell.exe -Command "& {gwmi Win32_Product -filter 'name like ''Java%'' AND vendor like ''Oracle%'' AND not version = ''8.0.770.3''' | % { $_.Name }}"
```

Of course, there are alternative ways to do the same thing.